# How to save multiple objects from a script in django shell

Tags: python, django, shell

Hello colleagues I would like to know if this list of objects can be saved from a script like the one I show, I want to execute it from the django shell

```
python3 manage.py shell < script.py
```

the following is my script

```
from orders_management.models import Products


objects = [
    'Products(name = "destornillador", section = "ferrreteria", price = 35)',
    'Products(name = "balon", section = "deportes", price = 25)',
    'Products(name = "raqueta", section = "deportes", price = 105)',
    'Products(name = "muneca", section = "juguetes", price = 15)',
    'Products(name = "tren electrico", section = "jugueteria", price = 135)',
]

for object in objects:
    my_product = object
    my_product.save()
```

the error it shows me

```
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have products wrapped in a string. Try it this way (without quotations around the products):

```
objects = [
    Products(name = "destornillador", section = "ferrreteria", price = 35),
    Products(name = "balon", section = "deportes", price = 25),
    Products(name = "raqueta", section = "deportes", price = 105),
    Products(name = "muneca", section = "juguetes", price = 15),
    Products(name = "tren electrico", section = "jugueteria", price = 135),
]

for object in objects:
    my_product = object
    my_product.save()
```

Comment: @AldoMatus If that is the case, could you accept my or Williem's answer?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `'Products()'` between single quotes, so as a `str`ing, not as a `Product` object.

Furthermore you better use [**`.bulk_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) instead of saving each object manually, since that will do it in a single query:

from orders_management.models import Products

```
objects = [
    # no '…'
    Products(name = "destornillador", section = "ferrreteria", price = 35),
    Products(name = "balon", section = "deportes", price = 25),
    Products(name = "raqueta", section = "deportes", price = 105),
    Products(name = "muneca", section = "juguetes", price = 15),
    Products(name = "tren electrico", section = "jugueteria", price = 135),
]

Products.objects.bulk_create(objects)
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Product` instead of <s>`Products`</s>.

Comment: IT WORKED! THANKS A LOT FRIEND Willem Van Onsem